# Is there a module that can list all the views on a system?

Tags: views

Is there a module that can list all the views installed on a system and their pages as well? If it can specify whether the Views are installed by modules or enduser created that will be helpful.

I am looking for something that create a list along this lines.

Name | Type of View | Page Name | Type of Page | Path

Comment: Views module lists views already, via Views UI. What's wrong with their native implementation?

Comment: @Mołot I need to export the information into a content type or a database, and adjust it and export it as I see fit. I'd prefer a module that has such a view, like Views System which can be cloned and extended

Comment: That's a very unusual request, I'd be quite surprised if anyone has written such a module (I can't imagine how it would be useful). Probably something you're going to have to write yourself to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a module already exists for that.

To build it yourself, you'll need to implement [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7), and describe the `views_view`, and `views_display` tables.

These are the columns you'll have available from the `views_view` table:

- name
- description
- tag
- base_table
- human_name
- core

And from `views_display`:

- vid (view id)
- id
- display_title
- display_plugin
- position
- display_options

`display_options` is a serialised PHP array of data (containing the path and other specific information), so unless you implement some pretty advanced field/filters/etc handlers you won't be able to filter on those specific elements, or use them as fields.

Comment: Does this mean the info for the separate pages of a view are stored in the display_options field rather than in separate database rows?

Comment: The displays themselves are each a row in the `views_display` table, but yeah, most of the useful data in there is in a serialised column (path, row style used, filters, etc)

Comment: I will accept it as it is as near an answer I'll get. I will delve into the Views module code later to see how the serialized info can be extracted

Comment: Make sure you get the [Advanced Help](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module installed for that; it's not exactly obvious, but there's a bunch of sample code for developing custom handlers buried in the Views section of that module. It's really useful, I'm not sure why they try so hard to hide it